# How to update tab title from Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I have an Activity inside the activity I have tab layout with two tabs(tab 1, tab 2). Each tab have recyclerview with list of items using Recycleradapter. I want to change the tab title when the user is clicking the recycler child item.

FYI :- I have a child clicklistener inside the adapter.

Activity code

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Tab1");

        adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "Tab2");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Adapter Code

```
holder.parentlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //I want to change the tab text here
    });
```

Comment: Could you share some snippet of your code?

Comment: Have you implemented a interface callback in your Adapter ?

Comment: You can use `Interface`

Comment: Can you give some sample for interface ? @Karacken

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Tab object from your TabLayout using following code and then you can apply your updated text in it:

```
mTabLayout.getTabAt(index).setText()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way make one method for title update into viewPagerAdapter like below..

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);

}

public void setTitle(String title)
{
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    mFragmentList = null;
    mFragmentTitleList = null;
    container.removeAllViews();
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

public  void updateTitle(String title,int position){
    mFragmentTitleList.set(position,title);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
}
```

then when you update title then call below method..

```
       mViewPagerAdapter.updateTitle("Your update title");
```